# XSLT concat many files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have many XML files like that :

File1.xml :

```
<Document xmlns="Forward">
   <Id>123456789</Id>
 </Document>
```

File2.xml :

```
<Document xmlns="Forward">
   <Id>4568844</Id>
 </Document>
```

I would like to concat these files and add prefix to the namespace like that :

Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mes:Fichier xmlns:mes="message">
  <mes:Rcvr>RECEIVE</mes:Rcvr>
  <doc:Document xmlns:doc="Forward">
    <doc:Id>123456789</doc:Id>
  </doc:Document>
  <doc:Document xmlns:doc="Forward">
    <doc:Id>4568844</doc:Id>
  </doc:Document>
</mes:Fichier>
```

My XLS :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:mes="message" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="Rcvr"/>
    <xsl:param name="fileList"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <mes:Fichier xmlns:mes="message" >
                <mes:Rcvr><xsl:value-of select="$Rcvr"/></mes:Rcvr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </mes:Fichier>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What exactly will be the contents of`$fileList`? Also, are you using an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: $fileList is not use now, i could put in this param my file list like "document(file1.xml) | document(file2.xml)" but i'm not sure .... Yes i can use an XSLT 2.0 Processor. Than you @michael.hor257k

Comment: I don't understand what your question is, then. Either use `tokenize()` on the `$fileList`, or perhaps have a look at the `collection()` function.

Comment: For example i have 3 files (file1.xml , file2.xml , file3.xml) each file contain an Document tag. I would like to concat all these files in the same file like the Output format i have describe in the topic.So in my XSL i don't know how i could iterate on each File.

Comment: (I have edited my topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two tasks, reading in a bunch of files and transforming them. Assuming Saxon 9 as your XSLT processor you can replace

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <mes:Fichier xmlns:mes="message" >
            <mes:Rcvr><xsl:value-of select="$Rcvr"/></mes:Rcvr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </mes:Fichier>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

with

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <mes:Fichier xmlns:mes="message" >
            <mes:Rcvr><xsl:value-of select="$Rcvr"/></mes:Rcvr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('.?select=file*.xml')/node()" />
        </mes:Fichier>
</xsl:template>
```

to read in and process all files named `file*.xml`.

Then for your transformation you want to add e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="doc:{local-name()}" namespace="Forward">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If there are more namespace involved you might need to restrict that match to the namespace you want to add the prefix to. And it makes sense to move the namespace declaration of your new root element to the root element of the stylesheet.

Comment: `collection` is a function defined in XPath 2.0 and later and as such available in XSLT 2.0 and later and XQuery 1.0 and later. That particular argument to read in files is Saxon 9 specific, see http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.html. A database oriented use of `collection` in e.g. BaseX or Marklogic might have different features.

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-collection for the definition of the `collection` function, but as said, the use of specific URIs is processor dependent.